# PHP running under "www-data" user

Tags: ubuntu, users, virtualbox, php

In PHP if I run `get_curret_user()` it prints `www-data`. This makes it impossible for me to use this function in order to test a FTP password from input.

Is there any way to make PHP run under the server admin user?

I changed APACHE_RUN_USER and APACHE_RUN_GROUP in /etc/apache2/envvars to my user name and "users" group, then restarted the server and it worked! But after that I made some changes to the hosts file, restarted apache, and now it runs again under www-data regardless of what's inside the envvars file!

Comment: Running stuff as root or with elevated permissions unless you absolutely must is a horrible idea

Comment: But then how can all the hosts run PHP as the user who bought the hosting package?

Comment: they don't. They just run everything as www-user with virtualhosts or its equivilent.

Comment: on my shared host if I run get_current_user() it prints my hosting account user name :| I have a local development ubuntu  server and I wanted to make it run the same way

Comment: nvm I did it by changing the UID to mine user id in the mount command for my www folder :x